# How to transform array of arrays into nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
const data = [
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"]
];
```

Here is the desired `output`:

```
const output = [
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      startTime: "10:00",
      endTime: "12:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "12:00",
      endTime: "13:00"
    },
    {
      startTime: "13:00",
      endTime: "14:30"
    }
  ]
];
```

Currently, I cannot get how to implement the nesting structure. Here is what I have tried so far to get the desired `output`:

```
const transformData = () => {
  return data.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      startTime: item[index],
      endTime: item[index + 1]
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: nesting structure == nested loops

Comment: ... or recursion :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that you should not override your existing array `data` with your desired result, as you will need to iterate over it from beginning to end, including iterating through each sub array. The desired `output` needs to be a **new** array instead.

Pass into your `transformData` the `data` object and have the function create a data structure with your desired `output` instead. I also modified the inner logic of getting the `startDate` and `endDate` via modulus math... like so:

```js
const data = [
  ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00"],
  ["01:30", "02:30", "03:30", "04:30"],
  ["02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00"],
  ["02:00", "03:30", "04:30", "05:30"],
  ["10:00", "10:01", "10:02", "10:03"],
  ["11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00"],
  ["21:00", "21:30", "23:00", "23:30"]
];

let transform = (someData) => {
    let output = [];

    someData && someData.forEach(arr => {
        output.push(arr.map((elem, index) => {
          return {
              [index % 2 === 0 ? 'startTime' : 'endTime']: elem
          };
        }));
    });

    return output;
};

// Using HTML element to display results

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(transform(data));
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to give the correct result. I believe the question would want `[{"startTime":"01:00","endTime":"02:00"},{"startTime":"02:00","endTime":"03:00"},{"startTime":"03:00","endTime":"04:00"}]` instead of `[{"startTime":"01:00"},{"endTime":"02:00"},{"startTime":"03:00"},{"endTime":"04:00"}]` for the first item in your example data.

Comment: @BenStephens you are right, I should have done an object comparison I just need to change the object key logic accordingly... editing now

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const transformData = (data) => {
  return data.map((items) => {
    const aux = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
      aux.push({
        startTime: items[i],
        endTime: items[i + 1]
      });
    }
    return aux;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```js
data.map((arr) => {
    let x = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        x.push({ startTime: arr[i], endTime: arr[i + 1] });
    }
    return x;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
const timeList = [
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
    ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"]
];

const getTimeTable = (timeData: string[]) => {
    return timeData.slice(0, 3).map((data, index: number) => ({ startDate: data, endDate: timeData[index + 1] }));
}
const value = timeList.map((x) => getTimeTable(x));

console.log('value', ...value);
```

Comment: `timeData.slice(0, 3)` would not account for timeData varying in length (this is not mentioned in the question, but it seems like a fair assumption to me); perhaps it could be `timeData.slice(0, -1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to create your new data structure for the inner array and then map over that. In the following example compile_times uses reduce to create the new inner array. The fourth argument of reduce is the entire array, and here `{ [i + 1]: endTime }` is used to pick the next item from the array and assign it to endTime.

```js
const data = [
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
  ["10:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:30"],
];

const compile_times = (times) =>
  times.reduce(
    (acc, startTime, i, { [i + 1]: endTime }) => endTime ?
      acc.concat({ startTime, endTime }) :
      acc,
    []
  );

const res = data.map(compile_times);

console.log(res);
```